# is_front_page not working in functions.php

Tags: functions, conditional-tags, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to include a CSS file using wp_enqueue_style conditionally on whether I am on the front page. I am testing for the home page with this code:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) wp_enqueue_style ('TBDhome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/TBDhome.css','all');
```

It worked find when I was testing in the header file and including the CSS file.

Comment: Do you have a style sheet with the `all` handle? You have that listed as a dependency. Can you post more code from your function? This isn't enough to help.

Comment: Where is this check happening? Is it happening inside an action/filter? Or are you straight up calling it right in the file outside any function? Keep in mind that when enquing styles and scripts it should be happening on the appropriate hook, don't just write random code in `functions.php` without using hooks/actions or it won't work as expected

Comment: Thanks. I don't have action/filter and I'm not sure how to create them. Where can I get information on these?

Comment: Google is your friend. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this question may get down voted - because not enough information has been provided and it's fairly easy to find tutorials elsewhere, I'll help you out.

In your `functions.php` file in your theme, you need to do this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp5849_scripts' );
function wp5849_scripts() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) :
        wp_enqueue_style('TBDhome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/TBDhome.css');
    endif;
}
```

What this is doing:
The first line `add_action` is the hook to run your function `wp5849_scripts()` at a certain point during WordPress's internal setup. You can read more about action hooks and filters in the [WordPress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/).

The second part is the actual function to enqueue the stylesheet. Checks to see if it's the front page of the site,  if it passes, it will load the stylesheet.

I updated the directory to be `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` because if you are using a child theme, `get_template_directory_uri()` will return the **PARENT** theme directory. `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will work with whatever theme is currently active (parent or child).

You can read more on the arguments that are passed to `wp_enqueue_style` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

As a note: you may already have a function that is enqueuing scripts and styles in your `functions.php` (look for the `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts')` hook). If that's the case, you simply need to add:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) :
        wp_enqueue_style('TBDhome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/TBDhome.css');
endif;
```

to the function that the `add_action` is calling. I wanted to add this as an option.

**EDIT:**
It appears there may be a larger theme issue or setting issue, based on OP comments. Here is an option to place the stylesheet in the header.php

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" id="TBDHome-css"  href="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/TBDhome.css" type='text/css' media='all' />
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this still isn't working. I am not getting any conditional style sheets added. My functions file looks like this: 'add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp5849_scripts' );
function wp5849_scripts() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) :
        wp_enqueue_style ('TBDhome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/TBDhome.css');
    endif;
}

Comment: What is the full directory to your CSS file? I can confirm that the code provided has been tested and works. So this leads me to believe your CSS file isn't in the directory or there is something else going on. Are you using a child theme?

Comment: The directory is http://www.tbdarchive2017.dev/wp-content/themes/TempleBethDavid/css. I print it out right before the function call and I have used it other places. It is not a child theme. I created the theme myself. This is the only thing I have right now in the function file.

Comment: Do you have the front-page set in Settings > Reading? The only thing that I can think of is that your home page is set to show posts in which case you would use `is_home()`

Comment: No, I'm testing other places and it shows up as front page. I'm totally stumped. Thanks though.

Comment: The code should be in functions.php, correct? Does it automatically get called or do I have to call it explicitly?

Comment: Yes, it should be in functions.php and the function should get called automatically. I'm going to make the assumption that your theme is loading correctly and that functions.php is in your theme folder. Try adding this to the top of your functions.php `echo 'hello'; if ( is_front_page() ) { echo ' front-page'; }` This way you can actually test if your functions.php is working and if you're on the front-page as well.

Comment: Good point. I thought i had tested this. I get the "hello" but not "front-page".  But even if I'm not testing for front_page, I'm not loading the style sheets.

Comment: Oops, I do get front-page. Correct syntax is if (is_front_page) echo.... (no extra () after front_page.

Comment: I'm not understanding. I see the correct syntax is how you have it with is_front_page(), but when I put the () in, it doesn't work! However, if I put the code in header.php, it works fine. For some reason it's not working in functions.php

Comment: There is something else going with your theme architecture or there is an incorrect setting. I've tested the code provided and it works. The other option is to not enqueue the script, but just place it in your header.php. I've updated my answer with that information.

Comment: Thank you. I have the code in my header but had read that enqueue is the better way to do it. I tried just pulling in one style sheet without the conditional and that doesn't work either. And I tried adding an echo inside the function and that didn't work. Shouldn't I be able to do this?

Comment: Does the first argument in the wp_enqueue have to be a particular name? I am not naming these style sheets anywhere.

Comment: The first argument is just an id that you can reference later. It can be anything you want it to be. If you clear everything out of your `functions.php` and just put in `echo 'hello';` does that render on your page? And yes, the echo should work in the function.

Comment: Yes, the echo 'hello' works. I put a function in with just an echo statement and called it from the header and that works too. But when I include it as part of  the function with the enqueue call, it doesn't work, as follows 'add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp5849_scripts' );
function wp5849_scripts() {
   // wp_enqueue_style ('TBDhome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/TBDhome.css');
 echo 'this is a function';
}' All I am doing is the echo here. Any ideas?

Comment: I can confirm just the `echo` works in the function. You don't have to keep testing the `header.php`. That's adding an unnecessary variable to troubleshooting. In the `wp5849_scripts()` function, remove everything except for an `echo`. You can also try adding `define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE);` to your `wp-config.php` to see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: So I tried using another theme to see what happens. I can see the echo statement executed inside the function. And I loaded the style sheet with your code and can see that it is loaded. How do I figure out what is wrong here? When I look in the debugger, I can see that the function is not being called.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that it does, as you suggested, work fine in another theme but not in mine. How can I begin to track this down?

Comment: There could be so many things to start with. Comments section not exactly the right place and it's a whole separate issue. However, I would appreciate you marking this as an accepted answer, as it really does answer the original question (despite theme errors).

Comment: two years on this answer helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Right on! Give it an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

`is_front_page()` will return false before the wp hook because the `wp` object is not set up yet.

```
//* If placed directly in functions.php, this will work
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_282498_wp' );
function wpse_282498_wp() {
  if( is_front_page() ) {
    do_something_useful();
  }
}

//* If placed directly in functions.php, this will *not* work
if( is_front_page() ) {
  //* Because this will never be run
  do_something_useful();
}
```

Comment: It turns out it's an issue with her theme - read the last two comments on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have created front-page.php in root folder.

Comment: In the root folder? You mean in the theme folder?

Comment: In any case I don't think is_front_page() actually requires a front-page template.